# What is special about this lookup field?

Tags: metadata, fields, standard, social

When using the Social Customer Service package, I noticed that the Parent field on the Social Post object had a unique lookup I hadn't seen anywhere else in the system.

[image]

Upon further investigation I noticed the standard Owner Field also has the same feature, with the ability to select between Contact and Queue.

Why are these fields locked away from us? Is there a way to create a custom field with the dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't currently use this functionality of a polymorphic custom lookup, but there is an idea for this in the success community:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqzBAAS

I definitely agree it would be a great addition to the platform!